# Accessing module methods with ::

Tags: ruby

Documentation I've read tells me to use Module.method to access methods in a module.  However, I can use Module::method as well.  Is this syntactic sugar, or am I confused?

```
module Cat
    FURRY_LEVEL = 4

    def self.sound
        %w{meow purr hiss zzzz}.sample
    end
end

puts Cat.sound          # This works.
puts Cat::sound         # This also works.  Why?!

puts Cat.FURRY_LEVEL    # Expected error occurs here.
puts Cat::FURRY_LEVEL   # This works.
```

Comment: You're not confused: both are legal. See my expanded answer below for why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constant resolution always requires that you use `::`.

Method invocation is idiomatically and usually a period (`.`), but `::` is also legal. This is not just true for so-called module methods, but for invoking any method on any object:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts "hi"
  end
end

Foo.new::bar
#=> hi
```

It's not so much "syntax sugar" as it is simply alternative syntax, such as the ability to write `if` or `case` statements with either a newline, `then` and newline, or just `then`.

It is specifically allowed because Ruby allows methods with the same name as a constant, and sometimes it makes sense to think that they are the same item:

```
class Foo
  class Bar
    attr_accessor :x
    def initialize( x )
      self.x = x
    end
  end
  def self.Bar( size )
    Foo::Bar.new( size ) 
  end
end

p Foo::Bar     #=> Foo::Bar                    (the class)
p Foo::Bar(42) #=> #<Foo::Bar:0x2d54fc0 @x=42> (instance result from method call)
```

You see this commonly in Ruby in the [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) library, which has (for example) the [`Nokogiri::XML`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML.html) module as well as the [`Nokogiri.XML`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri.html#method-c-XML) method. When creating an XML document, many people choose to write

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML( my_xml )
```

You see this also in the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) library, where you can write either:

```
class User < Sequel::Model                      # Simple class inheritance
class User < Sequel::Model(DB[:regular_users])  # Set which table to use
```

Again, we have a [method (Sequel.Model)](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel.html#method-c-Model) named the same as a [constant (Sequel::Model)](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model.html). The second line could also be written as

```
class User < Sequel.Model(DB[:regular_users])
```

…but it doesn't look quite as nice.

Comment: Some commonly known methods like this are `Array`, `Float`, `Integer`, and `String`.

Comment: @Josh Great examples (although I personally never, ever use those methods :)

Comment: just a sidenote :) "Constant resolution always requires that you use `::`" what about `#const_get`?

Answer (score 5):

The `::` is called `scope resolution operator`, which is used to find out under what `scope` the `method, class or constant` is defined.

In the following example, we use `::` to access class `Base` which is defined under module `ActiveRecord`

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
# => {:pool=>5, :timeout=>5000, :database=>"db/development.sqlite3", :adapter=>"sqlite3"}
```

We use `::` to access constants defined in module

```
> Cat::FURRY_LEVEL
=> 4
> Cat.FURRY_LEVEL
=> undefined method `FURRY_LEVEL' for Cat:Module (NoMethodError)
```

The `.` operator is used to call a `module method`(defined with self.) of a module.

Summary: Even though both `::` and `.` does the same job here, it is used for different purpose. You can read more from [here](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html).