# In ruby, the class name of File::Stat is strange?

Tags: ruby, class

In what situation,the double colon ,such as `File::Stat`, is allowed to used in class name? 
Does it have some special meaning?

Comment: There's some other great information in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314941/accessing-module-methods-with).

Answer (score 2):

It just means that the class in inside of another class or module.

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

You can't reference to Bar class just like that, you have to use its fully qualified name, `Foo::Bar` (there may be other Bar classes in other modules, so you have to be able to tell them apart).

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that the class is inside a module. It means that the *constant* is inside a module. There are no nested classes in Ruby like there are in Beta or Newspeak.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: there is truth and there is simplified truth :)

Answer (score 0):

The double colon signifies a module. Many times class names could conflict so people create a new module.

For example... `ActiveRecord::Base`

Answer (score 0):

Double colon is used when to get a CONSTANT in class or module (all capitalized objects are constants, such as VALUE_CONSTANT and ClassName). This is a convention inherited from C++ namespace concept.

So here the list of convention:

```
Module/Class::CONSTANT
Module/Class::Class
Module/Class.method
```