# Accessing Module Methods Best Practice ( '.' vs '::' )

Tags: ruby, class, methods, module, namespaces

Is it best practice to access module methods with a dot (`.`) or the scope resolution operator (`::`)?

I know both work and I understand the purpose of `::`, I would just like to know which to favour ***when accessing module methods*** and why.

Note: There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314941/accessing-module-methods-with) which goes into this topic, but not into which is better form.

Comment: I use dot syntax for this.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Why did you choose dot syntax over `::`?

Comment: `::` feels weird for this use case.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I agree, however I've definitely seen both used in the wild.

Comment: Matter of taste, I guess

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does :: (double colon) mean in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276905/what-does-double-colon-mean-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Both work but the [*Calling Methods*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Receiver) docs suggest that you should use `::` for namespaces:

> You may also use `::` to designate a receiver, but this is
>   rarely used due to the potential for confusion with `::`
>   for namespaces.

Comment: Yes! that's what Bala tried to say. Now you got the point.. :)